# Catching emails with Cypress-Mailosaur

Tags: cypress, cypress-mailosaur

I have a test where I need to test a confirmation link in an email being sent.

Im at a point where I am catching the email and getting the link, but when I then try to visit that link I am getting an error `link not defined`

```
  it("I fill out the form", () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("gettingStartedUrl"))
    cy.getElementById('firstName').click().type("Test")
    cy.getElementById('lastName').click().type("Test")
    cy.contains("Next").click()
  })
 it("I get the link from the confirmation email", () => {
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
      sentTo: emailAddress
    }).then(email => {
      expect(email.subject).to.equal('Welcome to Dashboard')
      confirmationLink = email.text.links[1].href;
    })
  })
  it('Visits the login link', () => {
    // This is where I get confirmationLink not defined
    cy.visit(confirmationLink)
  })
```

There is a second in the test runner that I can see it is trying to redirect to the right link, but then the test runner freezes up and I get the `confirmationLink is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

You can save the link to an environment variable

```js
 it("I fill out the form", () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("gettingStartedUrl"))
    cy.getElementById('firstName').click().type("Test")
    cy.getElementById('lastName').click().type("Test")
    cy.contains("Next").click()
  })
 it("I get the link from the confirmation email", () => {
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
      sentTo: emailAddress
    }).then(email => {
      expect(email.subject).to.equal('Welcome to Dashboard')
      Cypress.env('confirmationLink', email.text.links[1].href)
    })
  })
  it('Visits the login link', () => {
    // This is where I get confirmationLink not defined
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('confirmationLink'))
  })
```

Comment: When trying to save it as an env variable im getting `cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a url as its 1st argument ` I still see in the test runner that it does find the link I want it to redirect to. It then freezes up and fails with that error.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the 2nd and 3rd tests, they are really parts of the same test

```js
it("I fill out the form", () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("gettingStartedUrl"))
    cy.getElementById('firstName').click().type("Test")
    cy.getElementById('lastName').click().type("Test")
    cy.contains("Next").click()
  })
 it("I get the link from the confirmation email", () => {
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
      sentTo: emailAddress
    }).then(email => {
      expect(email.subject).to.equal('Welcome to Dashboard')
      const confirmationLink = email.text.links[1].href;
      cy.visit(confirmationLink)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the confirmationLink variable

```js
 let confirmationLink;

 it("I fill out the form", () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("gettingStartedUrl"))
    cy.getElementById('firstName').click().type("Test")
    cy.getElementById('lastName').click().type("Test")
    cy.contains("Next").click()
  })
 it("I get the link from the confirmation email", () => {
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
      sentTo: emailAddress
    }).then(email => {
      expect(email.subject).to.equal('Welcome to Dashboard')
      confirmationLink = email.text.links[1].href;
    })
  })

  it('Visits the login link', () => {
    const newOrigin = confirmationLink.split('?')[0] 
    cy.origin(newOrigin, { args: { confirmationLink } }, ({ confirmationLink }) => {
      cy.visit(confirmationLink)
    })
  })
```

Comment: I still get `confirmationLink not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the problem - is the link ok to visit? Try pasting it into a browser window.

Comment: Yeah, the  link works when visiting through the browser

Comment: It may be that the Cypress runner is getting reset completely when using `cy.visit()`. Normally links are tested with `cy.request(confirmationLink).then(() => { // check response here })`. What other checks do you want to do after the visit?

Comment: If it is resetting, you would see the page start to load, then clear and a 2nd attempt is made.

Comment: You can try visiting inside `cy.origin()` wrapper.

Comment: By the way, you need to set configuration `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` flag to `true`. I also added an extra line that was needed in another question (in case you need it too).

Comment: I ended up just making it all one command for now. I will revisit this in a few days and let you know if this worked.  Adding `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` started causing issues with retrieving the link from the email for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because the scope for the variable `confirmationLink` is local. To make sure you can access the link value in the next tests, you can use `Cypress.env()`, something like:

```js
it('I fill out the form', () => {
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('gettingStartedUrl'))
  cy.getElementById('firstName').click().type('Test')
  cy.getElementById('lastName').click().type('Test')
  cy.contains('Next').click()
})
it('I get the link from the confirmation email', () => {
  cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
    sentTo: emailAddress,
  }).then((email) => {
    expect(email.subject).to.equal('Welcome to Dashboard')
    Cypress.env('confirmationLink', email.text.links[1].href)
  })
})
it('Visits the login link', () => {
  // This is where I get confirmationLink not defined
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('confirmationLink'))
})
```

Comment: When trying to save it as an env variable im getting `cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a url as its 1st argument` I still see in the test runner that it  does find the link I want it to redirect to. It then freezes up and fails with that error.

Comment: can you log this `cy.log(email.text.links[1].href)` and check what you get ?

Comment: When I `cy.log` I get the link I am wanting to redirect to and I checked that the link does work when pasting it in my browser.

Comment: If you are getting a link(with https ike `https://www.google.com`) then the above should work. Add `trim()` just to make sure there aren't any empty spaces, `email.text.links[1].href.trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this way: Cypress.env('confirmationLink', email.text.links[0].href)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).